# Does exist PDF Reader with "next file" and "previous file" button?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I have a lot of one page pdf files. But the the only pdf reader I have installed (Foxit Reader) do not have a "Next file in folder" and "Previous file in folder" buttons.

Does exist such pdf reader, with buttons that I can push so that I can go to the next/previous pdf file inside current pdf file folder?

Comment: It's built-into macOS… but you didn't specify which OS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14886/lightweight-pdf-viewer-to-navigate-through-files-in-a-folder) at Software Recommendations says that SumatraPDF has a keyboard shortcut for this.

Comment: I found that Adobe Reader does not have such shortcut, but Adobe Acrobat does (Alt + Shift + Left Arrow = go to previous document and Alt + Shift + Right Arrow = go to next document). It seems that I will have to stick to Sumatra :)